# Pivot a groupby object in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [123, 'abc', '121'],
        [124, 'abc', '121'],
        [456, 'def', '121'],
        [123, 'abc', '122'],
        [123, 'abc', '122'],
        [456, 'def', '145'],
        [456, 'def', '145'],
        [456, 'def', '146'],
    ], columns=['userid', 'name', 'dt'])
```

I have grouped it according to the date:
`df2 = df.groupby('dt').apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True))`

Now, the dataframe looks like this:
[image]

Now, I want to pivot the above such that they are in this format:
`userid  name_1, name_2, ..., name_k` for each group such that the end df looks something like this:

```
userid   name
123      abc
124      abc
456      def
123      abc, abc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), where parameter index use columns `userid` and `dt`, so it looks like create `df2` is not necessary:

```
df['cols'] = 'name_' + (df.groupby(['userid','dt']).cumcount() + 1).astype(str)

print (df.pivot_table(index=['userid', 'dt'],columns='cols', values='name', aggfunc=''.join))
cols       name_1 name_2
userid dt               
123    121    abc   None
       122    abc    abc
124    121    abc   None
456    121    def   None
       145    def    def
       146    def   None
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out `groupby` and `apply`. Their respective docs are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html). You can `unstack` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)) the extra level of the MultiIndex that is created.

```
df = df.set_index(['userid', 'dt'])['name']
df = df.groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(
    lambda st: pd.Series(st.values, index=['name_%i'%i for i in range(st.shape[0])])
).unstack(level=-1)
print(df)
```

outputs

```
           name_0 name_1
userid dt               
123    121    abc   None
       122    abc    abc
124    121    abc   None
456    121    def   None
       145    def    def
       146    def   None
```